# Publish Subscribe service using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, publish-subscribe

I am using this code to create a factory for publishing and subscribing messages between controllers , directives and services .

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('TheCtrl', function($scope, NotifyingService) {
    $scope.notifications = 0;

    $scope.notify = function() {
        NotifyingService.publish();
    };

    // ... stuff ...
    NotifyingService.subscribe($scope, function somethingChanged() {
        // Handle notification
        $scope.notifications++;
    });
});

angular.module('app').factory('NotifyingService', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        subscribe: function(scope, callback) {
            var handler = $rootScope.$on('notifying-service-event', callback);
            scope.$on('$destroy', handler);
        },

        publish: function() {
            $rootScope.$emit('notifying-service-event');
        }
    };
});
```

It is working fine but I want to pass data while I am publishing to someone whos subscribing that ,how do I do that.
Suppose I want to publish a value of 4 , How do I perform that?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want to publish value `4` to the `'notifying-service-event'` and you want to use that value inside the subscriber.

In order to publish a value you need to pass it to your `emit` function.

```
publish: function(msg) {
            $rootScope.$emit('notifying-service-event', msg);
        }
```

Then, when you are using this publish function, pass the value you want.

```
node.on("click", click);

function click() {
  NotifyingService.publish(4);
}
```

While handling the `subscribe` event:

```
NotifyingService.subscribe($scope, function somethingChanged(event,msg) {
        console.log(msg); //4
        scope.number = msg //or whatever you want
        scope.$apply();
    });
```

you can find a full example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/CnoTA0kyW7hWWjI6DspS?p=preview

which was an answer to the question:
[Display informations about a bubble chart D3.js in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294036/display-informations-about-a-bubble-chart-d3-js-in-angularjs/37294478#37294478)