# Display informations about a bubble chart D3.js in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angular-directive, bubble-chart, angular-controller

I am searching how to display information about a bubble D3.js in AngularJS. I can show an alert with the desired information but I can't display informations on the page with AngularJS because I have no access to the $scope because my graphe is in a directive...
How can I pass the informations without change the structure of the web app ? I can't put the formation the bubble chart outsite of this directive.
This is my HTML :

```
  <body ng-app="d3DemoApp">
    <div id="graph1" ng-controller="controllerBubble">
      The package name should appear here : {{packageName}}
      <bubble-chart chart-data="chartData"></bubble-chart>
    </div>
  </body>
```

The service :

```
d3DemoApp.service('dataService', function AppCtrl($http, $q) {
  this.getCommitData = function(param) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: param
    }).
    success(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve({
        chartData: data,
        error: ''
      });
    }).
    error(function(data, status) {
      deferred.resolve({
        error: status
      });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };
});
```

The controller :

```
var d3DemoApp = angular.module('d3DemoApp', []);

// controller business logic
d3DemoApp.controller('controllerBubble', function AppCtrl($rootScope, $scope, dataService) {

  $scope.choice = 'data.json';

  loadData($scope.choice);

  function loadData(param) {
    dataService.getCommitData(param).then(function(res) {
      if (res.error) {
        $scope.error = res.error;
        return false;
      }
      $scope.chartData = res.chartData;
    });
  }

});


d3DemoApp.directive('bubbleChart', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      chartData: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      scope.$watch('chartData', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.info('new data comes to directive');
        console.info(newValue);
        if (newValue) {
          scope.drawChart(newValue);
        }
      });

      scope.drawChart = function(rootData) {

        var diameter = 900,
          format = d3.format(",d"),
          color = d3.scale.category20c();

        var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
          .sort(null)
          .size([diameter, diameter])
          .value(function(d) {
            return (d.numberOfLink + 1);
          })
          .padding(1.5);

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", diameter)
          .attr("height", diameter)
          .attr("class", "bubble");

        var filt = svg.append("defs")
          .append("filter")
          .attr({
            id: "f1",
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: "200%",
            height: "200%"
          });
        filt.append("feOffset").attr({
          result: "offOut",
          "in": "sourceAlpha",
          dx: 10,
          dy: 10
        });
        filt.append("feGaussianBlur").attr({
          result: "blurOut",
          "in": "offOut",
          stdDeviation: 10
        });
        var feMerge = filt.append("feMerge");
        feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "offsetBlur")
        feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
          .data(bubble.nodes(classes(rootData))
            .filter(function(d) {
              return !d.children;
            }))
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });

        node.append("title")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.className + ": " + format(d.value);
          });

        node.append("circle")
          .attr("r", function(d) {
            return d.r;
          })
          .style("fill", function(d) {
            return "red";
          });
        node.append("text")
          .attr("dy", ".3em")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3);
          })

        node.on("click", click);
        function click(d) {
          alert(d.packageName);
          $scope.packageName = d.packageName; // How to access to the scope ?
          }

        // Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
        function classes(root) {
          var classes = [];

          function recurse(name, node) {
            if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) {
              recurse(node.name, child);
            });
            else classes.push({
              packageName: name,
              className: node.name,
              value: node.numberOfLink,
              idProjet: node.projectId,
              numberOfLink: node.numberOfLink,
              priority: node.priority
            });
          }

          recurse(null, root);
          return {
            children: classes
          };
        }
        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
      }


      if (typeof scope.chartData != "undefined") {
        scope.drawChart(scope.chartData);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

This is an online example of the problem with Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/LUa7RHxjSaVe1KTzy33c?p=preview

Hope someone will can make works the Plunker ! Thanks.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the question. Do you need promt instead of alert? just replace alert with prompt ( https://plnkr.co/edit/Yj6XgLeSdvw7YwVKURbL?p=preview). What do you want to do with prompt?

Comment: Hello, I want the informations appears on my web page like in a paragraph or a div...

Comment: No, on my web page with this code : `The package name should appear here : {{packageName}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the result: https://plnkr.co/edit/CnoTA0kyW7hWWjI6DspS?p=preview

You have to create a shared service/factory between your controllers in order to do that. There are lots of examples out there.

```
angular.module('d3DemoApp').factory('NotifyingService', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        subscribe: function(scope, callback) {
            var handler = $rootScope.$on('notifying-service-event', callback);
            scope.$on('$destroy', handler);
        },

        notify: function(msg) {
            $rootScope.$emit('notifying-service-event', msg.packageName);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I already read that but I don't understand in my case how I should do it.

Comment: Hi, thanks it works, I would like to add other informations but it erase the first : https://plnkr.co/edit/f0D34h4LqXdlkENLZrDd?p=preview Can you check it ? Thanks.

Comment: @afeffifari-1957 I don't know what you've changed but here is a working one.. https://plnkr.co/edit/CnoTA0kyW7hWWjI6DspS?p=preview

Comment: @afeffifari-1957 You've set your `function somethingChanged(e,msg, msgPriority)` with 3 inputs but giving only 2 input here  `$rootScope.$emit('notifying-service-event', msg.packageName);`

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented in a different way, passing a variable from the parent scope to the directive which is in isolated scope mode was a good and clean solution for me, most of the open source project I have seen implemented in the same way. 
In that case you can even call functions inside your directive if it's related to your component workflow 
here is a link to the project and let me know what do you think 
https://github.com/amgadfahmi/angular-bubbletree